# MySQL - Get counts of `car models` by `car make`

Tags: mysql, query, select, pivot, count

I have a table with cars data, i.e. Makes, Models, & Year.

[image: Car data with its models & years]

I want to get the count for each Car with how many models it has... something like the image below:

[image: Makes with model count]

This is the SQL query I am using but it is giving me wrong counts. In fact, the number of rows against each car make is actually giving me my desired results.

```
SELECT `make`, COUNT(`id`) as `countmake`
FROM `cars_new`
WHERE 1
AND `make` IN ('Chrysler', 'Ferrari', 'Citroen', 'Dodge')
GROUP BY `model`
```

Help me to fix this!

Comment: Provide sample source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT NITO scripts. Provide3 desired output for provided data.

Comment: Show us what you would like the output to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found a solution to my problem. I am not sure if this is valid but it works for me.

```
SELECT `temp_table`.`make`, COUNT(temp_table.make) FROM (SELECT `make`, `model`, COUNT(`id`) as `tnncmake`
FROM `cars_new`
WHERE 1
AND `make` IN ('Chrysler', 'Ferrari', 'Citroen', 'Dodge')
GROUP BY `make`, `model`) `temp_table` where 1 GROUP BY `temp_table`.make
```

This gives me required results.

[image: Cars by Models]

I hope it helps someone else also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to GROUP BY both make and model, to get the count

```
SELECT `make`,`model`, COUNT(*) as `countmakemodel`
FROM `cars_new`
WHERE `make` IN ('Chrysler', 'Ferrari', 'Citroen', 'Dodge')
GROUP BY `make`,`model`
```